# Error (relating to colours) when trying to plot using heatmap.2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, heatmap

I'm trying to create a plot using `heatmap.2` but I keep receiving the error `must have one more break than colour`.

In case it's of interest I'm adapting this chap's code: https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/heatmaps_in_r.html

Here is the portion of the code in question:

```
# creates a own color palette 
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("snow", "yellow", "darkorange", "red"))(n = 299)

# (optional) defines the color breaks manually for a "skewed" color transition
col_breaks = c(seq(0,0.15,length=100), #white
               seq(0.16,0.29,length=100), # for yellow
               seq(0.3,0.5,length=100), # for orange
               seq(0.51,1,length=100))    # for red
```

Now something that is really confusing me is that this works:

```
# creates a own color palette 
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("snow", "yellow", "red"))(n = 299)


# (optional) defines the color breaks manually for a "skewed" color transition
col_breaks = c(seq(0,0.29,length=100),  #white
                  seq(0.3,0.5,length=100), # for yellow
                  seq(0.51,1,length=100))  # for red
```

As I seem to have modified the original code correctly once before I'm quite confused as to why I've failed to do so again.

Comment: Hi, wouldn't your example need `n=399` colours? Then the amount of breaks = amount of colours + 1

Comment: Yes, I had misunderstood the purpose of the number. If you respond with an answer instead of a comment I will mark it as solved for the next muppet that makes the same mistake. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
# creates a own color palette 
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("snow", "yellow", "darkorange", "red"))(n = 399)

# (optional) defines the color breaks manually for a "skewed" color transition
col_breaks = c(seq(0,0.15,length=100), #white
               seq(0.16,0.29,length=100), # for yellow
               seq(0.3,0.5,length=100), # for orange
               seq(0.51,1,length=100))    # for red
```

with the only relevant change being `n=399`, since you define col_breaks of length 400.